# Understanding a simple DISTINCT ON in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am having a small difficulty understanding the below simple DISTINCT ON query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (bcolor) bcolor,
    fcolor
FROM
    t1
ORDER BY
    bcolor,
    fcolor;
```

I have this table here:

[image]

What is the order of execution of the above table and why I am getting the following result:

[image]

As I understand since ORDER BY is used it will display the table columns (both of them), in alphabetical order and since ON is used it will return the 1st matched duplicate, but I am still confused about how the resulting table is displayed.

Can somebody take me through how exactly this query is executed ?

Comment: If it is anything like mysql, ORDER BY occurs after the SELECT results are calculated, so you won't get the alphabetically first fcolor for each bcolor.

Comment: What exactly is strange about the result? It's sorted the way you told Postgres to do.

Comment: @vhu Bug thanks you for editing !

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd one since you would think that the `SELECT` would happen first, then the `ORDER BY` like any normal RDBMS, but the `DISTINCT ON` is special. It needs to know the order of the records in order to properly determine which records should be dropped.

So, in this case, it orders first by the `bcolor`, then by the `fcolor`. Then it determines distinct `bcolor`s, and drops any but the first record for each distinct group.

In short, it does `ORDER BY` then applies the `DISTINCT ON` to drop the appropriate records. I think it would be most helpful to think of 'DISTINCT ON' as being special functionality that differs greatly from `DISTINCT`.

### Added after initial post:

This could be done using window functions and a subquery as well:

```
SELECT
    bcolor,
    fcolor
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bcolor ORDER BY fcolor ASC) as rownumber,
            bcolor,
            fcolor 
        FROM t1
    ) t2
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Comment: Oh now i get it , since i have done the following `ON (bcolor)` , its not going to allow any repetition , in the bcolor coloum right ? I.E. `blue` will appear just once in that coloum , so will `red` , and so will `green` , also `null` .